# Wpf Xaml how to add textblock to Canvas with existing items source?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am making a spectrogram program that displays the spectrogram as an image onto a canvas. I currently have the axis as well as other lines linked to the itemControl using binding. I want to be able to add text blocks to my canvas so that I can add values to the notches of the axis.

```
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Name="spectrogramScrollViewer" Loaded="SpectrogramScrollViewer_Loaded" >
                        <ItemsControl x:Name="SpecItem" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Lines}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel >
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Name="spectrogramTemplate">
                                    <Canvas Loaded="SpectrogramCanvas_Loaded" MouseUp="Spectrogram_MouseUp" MouseDown="Spectrogram_MouseDown" x:Name="SpectrogramCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Height="{Binding ImageHeight, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="{Binding ImageWidth, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            >
                                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                            <mouseMoveMvvm:MouseBehaviour MouseX="{Binding PanelX, Mode=OneWayToSource}" MouseY="{Binding PanelY, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
                                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                                        <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleTransformX}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleTransformY}"/>
                                        </Canvas.LayoutTransform>

                                        <Canvas.Background>
                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding SpectrogramImage, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                        </Canvas.Background>
                                    </Canvas>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}">

                                        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding CanvasLeft}" Y="{Binding CanvasTop}"/>
                                        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>

                                    </Rectangle>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. What I needed to make was a composite collection in the Window.Resources. This meant that the two objects collections were merged in the Xaml code and bound as such. I just needed to reference CombinedCollection in the itemsSource of my itemscontrol and my data template handled the rest.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ViewSource1" Source="{Binding TextValues}"></CollectionViewSource>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ViewSource2" Source="{Binding Lines}"></CollectionViewSource>

        <CompositeCollection x:Key="CombinedCollection">
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewSource1}}"></CollectionContainer>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewSource2}}"></CollectionContainer>
        </CompositeCollection>

</Window.Resources>
```